# Reading a Character Table in Magma

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters, magma-cas

These are the outputs of two character tables from Magma.  The first is for $A_5$.  The second is for $GL_3(2)$.  What is the significance of the '$+$' and '$0$' symbols?  I can produce more tables if it would be helpful in determining what these symbols mean.  $Z1$ in both cases is a polynomial expression evaluated at a root of unity, $\omega$, and $\#k$ means to replace $\omega$ with $\omega^k$ in this expression.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $+,0$ (and also sometimes $-$) symbols are the same as in the character tables
printed in the Atlas of Finite Groups.

It is called the *Frobenius-Schur Indicator*, and it is defined by

${\rm ind} \chi = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi(g^2).$

It actually takes the value $0,1$ or $-1$, and these are represented by $0.+,-$

It is equal to $0$ if $\chi$ takes non-real values, $1$ if the representation can be written over ${\mathbb R}$, and $-1$ if $\chi$ is real but the representation is not. For example $Q_8$ has a character with indicator $-1$.

Comment: Wonderful.  Thank you.